# Why is TRACE logging emitting as DEBUG using logging 1.1 and log4j 1.2.15

Tags: logging, log4j

I'm new to Java but I thought I understood the logging concepts.  From what I read, the TRACE level logging was enabled in v1.1 of commons-logging and 1.2.12 of log4j.

I'm using the following jars: commons-logging-api-1.1.jar & log4j-1.2.15.jar.

The code is:

```
if ( log.isTraceEnabled() ) {
  log.trace("some text");
}
```

However, it's emitting when my log4j.properties setting is DEBUG and the output is tagged as "DEBUG".

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trace` is finer grained than `debug`.  That explains why you are seeing trace statements when the setting is for debug (or finer).  As for why it is tagged `debug` -- commons logging is responsible for that.  See http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-TRACE-vs-DEBUG-p4146626.html.